# Vue.js with widget js file containing document.write

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I know how to load external js files to Vue.js or Nuxt.js but I have a specific problem with eg. french Shom Widget files.
Shom (for tides predictions) give access to a widget via a js file containing a lot of dirty document.write (you can see a sample at https://services.data.shom.fr/hdm/vignette/grande/CAP_FERRET?locale=fr)

```
var rid="vignette_shom_"+Math.round(Math.random()*10000000);
document.write("<iframe width='675' id='"+rid+"' height='900' frameborder='0' scrolling='no'></iframe>");var ifrm = document.getElementById(rid);ifrm = (ifrm.contentWindow) ? ifrm.contentWindow : (ifrm.contentDocument.document) ? ifrm.contentDocument.document:ifrm.contentDocument;ifrm.document.open();
ifrm.document.write('<!DOCTYPE html>');ifrm.document.write('<html>');ifrm.document.write('<head>');
```

.. ans so on...

Trying to load this script into the mounted method is ok, but i'm unable to display content into component.

Any idea ?
thanks